# Are there any legal ramifications for sexual harassment in general?

Tags: sexual-offences

I’ve usual heard of sexual harassment being grounds for dismissal from a workplace, or for general public disgrace. However, is it illegal if you feel someone sexually harasses you, in general? Can you report them to the police? Or is the only option a personal lawsuit against them?

How common is it for there to be legal ramifications for sexual harassment? Is it something that ultimately people get off the hook with because it’s not as forbidden as sexual assault?

Answer (score 2):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

Sexual harassment is a civil wrong which is a form of discrimination in employment. It can also sometimes give rise to other civil wrongs called torts, like intentional infliction of emotional distress/outrageous conduct, or a civil assault and battery claim.

The usual process, for sexual harassment at a private employer in the U.S., is to file a complaint with the Equal Opportunity Employment Commission within six months of the harassment. Then, the EEOC evaluates the claim and either brings a lawsuit against the employer and harasser itself, or declines to do so and gives the employee a "no action letter" which authorizes the employee to hire their own lawyer and sue these people without EEOC involvement.

Different rules and procedures often apply in unionized workplaces, in the military, and for government employees. There is also minor variation from state to state under state sexual harassment laws as opposed to federal employment discrimination laws. Different rules and procedures also apply to sexual harassment outside the employer-employee context.

While touching without consent or sexual assault, and certain other kinds of conduct that amount to sexual harassment (e.g. extortion), are crimes (typically under state law), that can be enforced by government prosecutors in their discretion, most kinds of sexual harassment are not crimes.

> How common is it for there to be legal ramifications for sexual
> harassment? Is it something that ultimately people get off the hook
> with because it’s not as forbidden as sexual assault?

The most common outcome is that it isn't reported in timely manner to the EEOC, does not amount to a crime, or is reported to HR or a supervisor who do nothing, and nothing happens.

The next most common outcome is that it is reported to HR or a supervisor, the employee is fired or disciplined or shapes up, and the person who is harassed is satisfied and does nothing more.

But when a complaint is filed with the EEOC, or a lawsuit is filed by a lawyer following an EEOC "no action letter", significant monetary settlements are common (maybe 90%+ of the time). When cases do go to trial (typically the close cases, but sometimes just due to the egos of the people involved), there is a verdict against the alleged sexual harasser about half the time with often very substantial jury awards, and there is a defense verdict about half the time.

When a prosecutor decides that the sexual harassment included criminal conduct such as sexual contact without consent, there is a plea bargain about 90% of the time, and a jury verdict finding the defendant to be guilty more than half of the time. The sentence imposed depends upon the charge of conviction, the nature of the conduct, the laws of the place where the charges are brought, and some factors related to the defendant in general, such as whether the defendant has a prior criminal record.

Comment: While that is a very good description, I feel like the OP already knew. You buried the answer to the actual question "I know it's reason for dismissal and lawsuits, but is it a crime" deeply within all the other information and mostly by not mentioning it explicitely. Did I get it correctly, that the answer is "it's not, not by itself"?

Comment: @novoigt Sexual harassment is a broad term which includes some things that a criminal and some things that are not.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers go on tangent about the workplace, so let me clarify: You asked whether what would be considered "sexual harassment" in the workplace, would be a criminal act *outside* of the workplace.

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Sexual harassment is not illegal in itself, between two private adults outside of the workplace or related areas or environments.

Sexual Harassment *can* include other acts, that *are* indeed illegal:

- Physical *acts* are covered under sexual assault (§ 184i StGB) and are illegal without consent.
- Plain words between adults, depending on what is actually said, written or implied and who overhears it, may be insulting or defamation (§185 StGB, §186 StGB, §187 StGB).
- Obviously, minors are a whole different topic.

But if it does not include any of those, even if it would be considered "sexual harassment" in the workplace, between two private adult persons, no crime was committed.

So for example if someone comes up to you on the street and says "I am attracted to you, want to have sex?" and they accept an "ew, no!" and walk away and never ask again, then that is not illegal, although it would certainly be sexual harassment if that had happened between workers in their workplace.

Comment: Harrassment is not illegal?

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Specific forms of harassment are illegal. But what is considered "sexual harassment" in the workplace, if not running afoul of the laws mentioned in my answer, is not illegal outside of the workplace. So for example if someone comes up to you on the street and says "I am attracted to you, want to have sex?" and they accept a "ew, no!" and walk away, I don't know which law that would break. Because that was neither insulting, nor physical. It would only be "sexual harassment" in the workplace (and related environments).

Answer (score -1):

### The employer is responsible for [sexual harassment](https://www.fairwork.gov.au/employment-conditions/bullying-sexual-harassment-and-discrimination-at-work/sexual-harassment-in-the-workplace#positive-duty-under-the-sex-discrimination-act)

[australia](/questions/tagged/australia)

The law creates a positive duty on the employer to prevent and manage sexual harassment in the workplace. So, if you sue anyone, you sue your employer; not the person who sexually harassed you.

### Some sexual harassment is criminal, some isn’t

> Sexual harassment is:
>
> - an unwelcome sexual advance or request for sexual favours to the person who is harassed
> - other unwelcome conduct of a sexual nature in relation to the person who is harassed.
>
> To be sexual harassment, it has to be reasonable to expect that there is a possibility that the person being harassed would be offended, humiliated or intimidated by the behaviour. This means that whether behaviour is sexual harassment depends on how a reasonable person would interpret the behaviour in that situation. Behaviour that is sexual harassment in one situation may not be in a different situation.
>
> When working out whether certain conduct is sexual harassment, the intention of the alleged harasser doesn’t matter.

Asking someone for sex is not a crime but it might be sexual harassment. Non-consensual sexual touching is both a crime and sexual harassment.

Comment: Can you link some codified criminal offences which are sexual harassment?